# How to process the order if user closes the browser

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, up-sells

I am looking at how to implement upsell checkout functionality, this is how it should work.

**Step 1*8. User go to the site then add product to the cart, and click the “checkout” button take them to the checkout page (one page checkout).

**Step 2**. User enter their shipping, billing and credit card information then click the “Process Order” button. Once user click the “Process Order” button the initial purchase is completed and take them to the first post up sell page.

**Step 3**. On the first post up sell page user have an option to buy additional product with “Yes” or “No” button.

**Step 4**. If user click the “No” button they will see the second post up sell page. If user click the “Yes” button they will see the post up sell confirmation page.

**Step 5**. On the post up sell confirmation page, user have option to continue with the initial purchase (step2) or they can update the order with additional item they purchased on the post up sell page.

I need to figure it out how to process the initial purchase (step2) and store the order details on the database and send the order confirmation email to the user if user close the browser on step 3.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what u  mean by capture ? and which page are you calling as confirmation pagw

Comment: in the checkout page after user enter the credit card information and click on the "order" button then it will go to the confirmation page, in this page i wanted to display up sell product, if user don't like and close the browser i need to process the initial order and send the order confirmation email.

Comment: This will be hard to achieve without heavy customization. The problem is that if you use some online payment processor the amount authorized and/or captured is for original order. Magento by default does not allow editing of the orders. What it does it cancels the original order and creates a new one with updated items. But card transaction does not allow you to cancel the order without credit memo. You could try to create a second order for upsell item. But then user will have to do 2nd  payment. You could also move this upsell to popup after hitting place order but before actually doing it.

Comment: I think the credit card problem can be fix with  "Authorization Reversal Transactions", but I am stuck at when user closed the browser how to process the initial order.